# Convert perl one liner to script

Tags: regex, perl

I am Vijay and i am a student and very much interested to learn perl scripting.
I was learning about perl on liner. 
I would like to write a perl script that goes through the file line by line and compares each line with the previous line (or next line) to look for matching values in the first 3 columns. Then I would like to print the values in the first three columns only once, with the fourth column value pushed on as new column.For example

```
1 760605 769233 15.65  
1 760605 769233 44.11  
1 760605 769233 18.5
```

Output should be

```
1 760605 769233 15.65 44.11 18.5
```

The one liner for this is

```
perl -ape '$k="@F[0..2]"; $_=" $F[3]",next if $k eq $o; $_= "\n@F";$o=$k' filename
```

Here i want to covert this into script and run that script. If i get to know how to convert this above one liner to scripting it will be great full and i can implement the same logic to others also.

Thank you.

Comment: Re "_I would like to write a perl script_" --- then do so! I'd suggest to not worry about translating some random code you find around, but rather work it out yourself.  If in the process you need a programming (and/or Perl) tutorial, even better.  (Also, one-liners in particular are often poor sources to use for learning as they rely on tricks to keep things short.)

Comment: A good first start for getting a rough outline of a script from a oneliner is to use the `B::Deparse` module: `perl -MO=Deparse -ape '$k="@F[0..2]"; $_=" $F[3]",next if $k eq $o; $_= "\n@F";$o=$k' filename`. You will still need to learn how to program though.

Answer (score 2):

As @Corion said, [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) can help here.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ape '$k="@F[0..2]"; $_=" $F[3]",next if $k eq $o; $_= "\n@F";$o=$k'
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    our @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    $k = join($", @F[0..2]);
    $_ = " $F[3]", next if $k eq $o;
    $_ = "\n@F";
    $o = $k;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Cleaning that up into a pretty much equivalent script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $o;
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    my @fields = split ' ', $line;
    my $k = "@fields[0..2]";
    if (defined $o && $k eq $o) {
        $line = " $fields[3]";
        next;
    }
    $line = "\n@fields";
    $o = $k;
} continue { print $line }
```